# How to get the basis of $L^2[0,1]$ from the basis of $L^2[0,2]$

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

Is there any way to derive orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$ from the orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,2]$?

Here $L^2[0,2]$: is space of square integrable centered stochastic process on $\Omega\times[0,2]$, with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$.

Comment: I actually think you could simply restrict the functions $\{e_n\}$ to $[0,1]$, this should give you a generating set but most likely not a basis, but of course this is less than what you want...

Comment: @user190080. You are right,  I am looking for basis functions. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any unitary operator $U:L^2[0,2]\to L^2[0,1]$. Then the set of $f_k:=Ue_k$ is an orthonormal base in $L^2[0,1]$.

An example of such operator is
$$(Uf)(s)=\sqrt 2 f(2s),\ f\in L^2[0,2],\  s\in[0,1].$$

Comment: hmm... I don't quite see how this works, I mean take $e_1\in L^2[0,2]$ and then apply the given operator, then we want to check for instance the normality, so $\int_{0}^{1}||\sqrt{2}e_1(2s)||^2ds=\int_{0}^{1}||e_1(u)||^2du$ and why would this equal $1$?

Comment: The following is true: $\int_0^1|\sqrt 2 e_1(2s)|^2ds=\int_0^2| e_1(u)|^2du$. This means that $U$ is isometric. Since $U$ is surjective, $U$ is unitary.

Comment: uhhh... I did a mistake in the substitution...